# print a result with some calculation of two numbers

Tags: python, pandas

How can I print out result of simple calculation with reference to some pandas column?

I can print out the two values like this:

```
print("The values are {} and {}".format(*average_revenue['revenue']))
```

If I want to print the difference, is there a simple way by just doing it in the print function?

The following will simply print out the description but doesn't provide me a result.

```
print("The incremental value is {} - {}".format(*average_revenue['revenue']))
```

Comment: First of all, is the element inside `average_revenue['revenue']` a container of two values?

Comment: Yes there are only two values.

Comment: @Which container it is ? `list`? `tuple`? I mean what `average_revenue['revenue']` exactly returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: I'm assuming`average_revenue['revenue']` only contains those two values. Below solutions will yield unexpected results otherwise.

---

Rather simple with [`numpy.subtract`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html):

```py
import numpy as np

# ...

print("The incremental value is {}".format(np.subtract(*average_revenue['revenue'])))
```

The above approach cares about the order of the arguments, so it might yield a negative value. If you want to always show positive differences, then we can print the absolute value of the difference:

```
print("The incremental value is {}".format(abs(np.subtract(*average_revenue['revenue']))))
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to use `numpy`, you can still have it functional-style with [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`operator.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.sub):

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

# ...

print("The incremental value is {}".format(reduce(operator.sub, average_revenue['revenue'])))
```

Comment: Thanks, will I be able to control which number being subtracted? - just try to avoid the result being negative.

Comment: @sylvia You can't with these solutions. The subtraction is done in the same order as they are rows in the dataframe. To work around this you can wrap everything around `abs`, i.e. `abs(np.subtract(*average_revenue['revenue']))` - I'll update my asnwer accordingly